# Array groupping with condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So i have an array of response from BE with structure like this:

```
    const answer= [
  {
    "Tanggal": "2023-01-05",
    "Plant": "Ranc",
    "Gedung / Zona": "Zona 2",
    "Sektor": "9",
    "Line": "34",
    "Shift Running": "3",
    "SKU Number": "310902",
    "RPH Input": "Planned (H-1)"
  },
  {
    "Tanggal": "2023-01-05",
    "Plant": "Ranc",
    "Gedung / Zona": "Zona 2",
    "Sektor": "9",
    "Line": "34",
    "Shift Running": "2",
    "SKU Number": "310902",
    "RPH Input": "Revisi"
  },
  {
    "Tanggal": "2023-01-05",
    "Plant": "Ranc",
    "Gedung / Zona": "Zona 2",
    "Sektor": "9",
    "Line": "36",
    "Shift Running": "3",
    "SKU Number": "300360",
    "RPH Input": "Planned (H-1)"
  },
  {
    "Tanggal": "2023-01-05",
    "Plant": "Ranc",
    "Gedung / Zona": "Zona 2",
    "Sektor": "9",
    "Line": "36",
    "Shift Running": "3",
    "SKU Number": "310907",
    "RPH Input": "Planned (H-1)"
  },
  {
    "Tanggal": "2023-01-05",
    "Plant": "Ranc",
    "Gedung / Zona": "Zona 2",
    "Sektor": "9",
    "Line": "37",
    "Shift Running": "3",
    "SKU Number": "310908",
    "RPH Input": "Planned (H-1)"
  },
  {
    "Tanggal": "2023-01-05",
    "Plant": "Ranc",
    "Gedung / Zona": "Zona 2",
    "Sektor": "11",
    "Line": "43",
    "Shift Running": "1",
    "SKU Number": "310101",
    "RPH Input": "Planned (H-1)"
  },
  {
    "Tanggal": "2023-01-06",
    "Plant": "Ranc",
    "Gedung / Zona": "Zona 2",
    "Sektor": "11",
    "Line": "44",
    "Shift Running": "2",
    "SKU Number": "321294",
    "RPH Input": "Planned (H-1)"
  },
  {
    "Tanggal": "2023-01-06",
    "Plant": "Ranc",
    "Gedung / Zona": "Zona 2",
    "Sektor": "11",
    "Line": "44",
    "Shift Running": "3",
    "SKU Number": "300079",
    "RPH Input": "Revisi"
  }
];
```

i try to grouped it into date with condition if the "Tanggal","Plant","Gedung/Zona","sektor",Line and SKU number is the same (excl. shift number) but the RPH input has value "Revisi", it will only group the value from RPH input that has value revisi instead of the Planned (H-1), with expected array to be like this, the value of the date is the accumulated value from Shift Running (here is the expected array):

```
const tranfrdata=[{ "2023-01-05": 12,
  "2023-01-06": 5 }]
```

it possible to just group it based on the logic i mention above, is that possible to do that? or any help on this?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this question. Is just that you want to add up Shift Running by date, but excluding any with RPH Input of Revisi? Can we ignore the other fields?

Comment: uhm not excluding, so let say i have two condition which the tanggal,plant,gedung and etc has the same value but the RPH input has "Planned H-1" and "Revisi",so it only choose the "Revisi" instead of the "planned H-1", and addup shift running by date..

Comment: Can you have two items with the same Tanggal, Plant, Gedung / Zona, Sektor, Line, SKU Number and RPH Input in the source data?

Comment: i have put it on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to process Revisi items first and then ignore any subsequent items that have the same Tanggal, Plant, Gedung / Zona, Sektor, Line and SKU Number when accumulating the Shift Running number.

```js
const answer = [{"Tanggal":"2023-01-05","Plant":"Ranc","Gedung / Zona":"Zona 2","Sektor":"9","Line":"34","Shift Running":"3","SKU Number":"310902","RPH Input":"Planned (H-1)"},{"Tanggal":"2023-01-05","Plant":"Ranc","Gedung / Zona":"Zona 2","Sektor":"9","Line":"34","Shift Running":"2","SKU Number":"310902","RPH Input":"Revisi"},{"Tanggal":"2023-01-05","Plant":"Ranc","Gedung / Zona":"Zona 2","Sektor":"9","Line":"36","Shift Running":"3","SKU Number":"300360","RPH Input":"Planned (H-1)"},{"Tanggal":"2023-01-05","Plant":"Ranc","Gedung / Zona":"Zona 2","Sektor":"9","Line":"36","Shift Running":"3","SKU Number":"310907","RPH Input":"Planned (H-1)"},{"Tanggal":"2023-01-05","Plant":"Ranc","Gedung / Zona":"Zona 2","Sektor":"9","Line":"37","Shift Running":"3","SKU Number":"310908","RPH Input":"Planned (H-1)"},{"Tanggal":"2023-01-05","Plant":"Ranc","Gedung / Zona":"Zona 2","Sektor":"11","Line":"43","Shift Running":"1","SKU Number":"310101","RPH Input":"Planned (H-1)"},{"Tanggal":"2023-01-06","Plant":"Ranc","Gedung / Zona":"Zona 2","Sektor":"11","Line":"44","Shift Running":"2","SKU Number":"321294","RPH Input":"Planned (H-1)"},{"Tanggal":"2023-01-06","Plant":"Ranc","Gedung / Zona":"Zona 2","Sektor":"11","Line":"44","Shift Running":"3","SKU Number":"300079","RPH Input":"Revisi"}];

const make_ident = ({
  Tanggal, Plant, ["Gedung / Zona"]: Zona, Sektor, Line, ["SKU Number"]: SKU
}) => {
  return Tanggal + '::' + Plant + '::' + Zona + '::' + Sektor + '::' +
    Line + '::' + SKU;
};

const sum_shifts_by_date = (data) => {
  // sort Revisi to the top of the array
  const sorted = [...data].sort((a, b) =>
    (a['RPH Input'] === b['RPH Input']) ? 0 :
      (a['RPH Input'] === 'Revisi' && b['RPH Input'] !== 'Revisi') ? -1 :
      1
  );
  
  const found = new Set();
  
  return sorted.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const { Tanggal, ["Shift Running"]: count } = item;
    const ident = make_ident(item);
    
    if(found.has(ident))
      return acc;
    
    // add ident to the found set so if we encounter the same details again
    // they'll be ignored (we've sorted Revisi to the top so we should be
    // ignoring any Planned (H-1) with the same details)
    found.add(ident);
    
    return { ...acc, [Tanggal]: (acc[Tanggal] || 0) + Number(count) };
  }, {});
};

console.log(sum_shifts_by_date(answer));
```

Comment: got an error.. return { ...acc, [Tanggal]: (acc[Tanggal] ?? 0) + Number(count) };
                                               ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

Comment: @nabatiadmin I've changed `??` to `||`, does that help? What version of Javascript/ECMAScript is this running in?

Comment: Javascript/ECMAScript 6

Comment: Works with every condition, thanks a lot....

Comment: but i am getting some bugs here @Ben Stephens..., if i have the same object twice, it will not accumulated even if it has the same "Planned (H-1)"\

Comment: This is why I asked "Can you have two items with the same Tanggal, Plant, Gedung / Zona, Sektor, Line, SKU Number and RPH Input in the source data?" in the question comments. If you can have two Planned (H-1) items with the same details how would you know which one a Revisi item (with the same details) would apply to?

Comment: damn, i just understand your code, no more bugs, my bad, sorry for that sir, thanks a lottttt

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think the best way is to separate the array to `Planned (H-1)` and `Revisi`, then iterate the first array and check if it exists in the second array by using the SKU Number, and if it doesn't just accumulate from the first array, and if it does, accumulate from the second array:

```js
const answer = [{
    "Tanggal": "2023-01-05",
    "Plant": "Ranc",
    "Gedung / Zona": "Zona 2",
    "Sektor": "9",
    "Line": "34",
    "Shift Running": "3",
    "SKU Number": "310902",
    "RPH Input": "Planned (H-1)"
  },
  {
    "Tanggal": "2023-01-05",
    "Plant": "Ranc",
    "Gedung / Zona": "Zona 2",
    "Sektor": "9",
    "Line": "34",
    "Shift Running": "2",
    "SKU Number": "310902",
    "RPH Input": "Revisi"
  },
  {
    "Tanggal": "2023-01-05",
    "Plant": "Ranc",
    "Gedung / Zona": "Zona 2",
    "Sektor": "9",
    "Line": "36",
    "Shift Running": "3",
    "SKU Number": "300360",
    "RPH Input": "Planned (H-1)"
  },
  {
    "Tanggal": "2023-01-05",
    "Plant": "Ranc",
    "Gedung / Zona": "Zona 2",
    "Sektor": "9",
    "Line": "36",
    "Shift Running": "3",
    "SKU Number": "310907",
    "RPH Input": "Planned (H-1)"
  },
  {
    "Tanggal": "2023-01-05",
    "Plant": "Ranc",
    "Gedung / Zona": "Zona 2",
    "Sektor": "9",
    "Line": "37",
    "Shift Running": "3",
    "SKU Number": "310908",
    "RPH Input": "Planned (H-1)"
  },
  {
    "Tanggal": "2023-01-05",
    "Plant": "Ranc",
    "Gedung / Zona": "Zona 2",
    "Sektor": "11",
    "Line": "43",
    "Shift Running": "1",
    "SKU Number": "310101",
    "RPH Input": "Planned (H-1)"
  },
  {
    "Tanggal": "2023-01-06",
    "Plant": "Ranc",
    "Gedung / Zona": "Zona 2",
    "Sektor": "11",
    "Line": "44",
    "Shift Running": "2",
    "SKU Number": "321294",
    "RPH Input": "Planned (H-1)"
  },
  {
    "Tanggal": "2023-01-06",
    "Plant": "Ranc",
    "Gedung / Zona": "Zona 2",
    "Sektor": "11",
    "Line": "44",
    "Shift Running": "3",
    "SKU Number": "300079",
    "RPH Input": "Revisi"
  }
];

const planned = answer.filter(obj => obj["RPH Input"] === "Planned (H-1)")
const revisi = answer.filter(obj => obj["RPH Input"] === "Revisi")

const transferData = answer.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let compareObj, inPlanned
  if (curr["RPH Input"] === "Planned (H-1)") {
    compareObj = revisi.find(obj => obj["SKU Number"] === curr["SKU Number"])
  } else { // revisi
    inPlanned = planned.find(obj => obj["SKU Number"] === curr["SKU Number"])
  }


  let finalObj = curr
  if (compareObj) {
    finalObj = compareObj
  }

  if (!inPlanned) {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [finalObj["Tanggal"]]: finalObj["Tanggal"] in acc ? acc[finalObj["Tanggal"]] + Number(finalObj["Shift Running"]) : Number(finalObj["Shift Running"])
    }
  }
  return {
    ...acc,
  }
}, {})



console.log(transferData)
```

Comment: got an error bro... "revisi.findLast is not a function"

Comment: but the answer is already what i expected..

Comment: @nabatiadmin if the error happens after you apply the code on your end, then it's hard to debug from here, there might be some different structure on your end, maybe try to change `findLast` to `find` and see if it works

Comment: it works but when it come to different condition i think it has some issue..., do you mind to take a look on it sir? @Damzaky

Comment: @nabatiadmin ok so what's the error? is it a wrong output with the new array you updated on question? what's the expected output?

Comment: i think we need to excl the shift running... because even if it has the same value it my differ the shift running and causing bugs on it...

Comment: if you use the array that i updated, the result on '2023-01-06' will be 2 when actually it should be 5.., any help on that? @Damzaky

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250942/discussion-between-nabati-admin-and-damzaky).